# Git log list commits excluding cherry-picked from the first branch

Tags: git, github

For example I have this commit history

[image: git history]
[image]

Let say at some point `release1` was released to production and after couple of days, `release2` branch was released.

- branch `relase1` contains 2 commits (4 & 5) that was cherry-picked from master
- branch `release2` contains 2 commits (8 & 9) that was also cherry-picked from master.

cherry-pick was never done with `-x` argument.

I want to get all commit for `release2` that "wasn't release yet at that point" this means commit (6,7,8,9) that is marked by green circle.

What would be the easiest way to do this?

Example of the repository in [github](https://github.com/yulrizka/git-question)

**Update 1 (git cherry)**

```
$ git cherry -v release1 release2
- 91785f2be363244a1da4459746fce6a6ea28c2b5 4
- e88de1f8b62213089b300e3143c4caf509b5c13b 5
- 9d23e9c7e6f769c3bbb44ad42bc7b708b4b0a9e6 6
- 6fb71e4406e0b127e06f6e5b145de8a9d39db01e 7
- 6276becc413494b7724a4dd8b852234f4b71e913 8
- 6dd3b5b75222c02c921c9c20bcaee83e1c8be746 9
```

With `cherry`, it seems that I still got 4 and 5 which both are form master

**Update 2 (--left-right --cherry-mark)**

```
$ git log --left-right --cherry-mark --pretty=oneline --abbrev-commit  release2...release1
= 6dd3b5b 9
= 6276bec 8
> caa4e2f 5
= 0230a1f 4
= 6fb71e4 7
= 9d23e9c 6
= e88de1f 5
= 91785f2 4
```

This gives me everything except 5 is cherry-marked, which I have a hard time to explain

**Update 3 with non empty commit**

In original attempt, I created each commit with `--allow-empty`. As pointed below it created hash of an empty tree.

After recreating the the repository with real content, I get the desire result with both answer below `git cherry` and `--left-right --cherry-mark`

Comment: would have been easier if you had merged instead of cherry picked

Comment: you repo do not have branch...

Comment: sorry you are right, pushed all the branch

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Note that [your linked repository](https://github.com/yulrizka/git-question) contains 15 completely empty commits.  By "empty commits" I don't just mean the kind of no-change commits that `git commit --allow-empty` allows, but rather *completely* empty: each commit has no files at all, just a commit message.  (More precisely, every commit has the [empty tree `4b825dc642cb6eb9a060e54bf8d69288fbee4904`](https://stackoverflow.com/q/9765453/1256452) as its tree.)  So *every* commit in your repository is patch-ID equivalent to *every other* commit in your repository.

That (mostly) explains why your update-2 section shows the output that it does: commit `6dd3b5b` is patch-equivalent to commits `6276bec`, `9d23e9c`, and so on.  The puzzle is why commit `caa4e2f` is not paired up with another, since it too is patch-equivalent to every other commit.  In any case, this is almost an example of a false positive, but here it's really more of a true positive: these commits *are* all the same, and can therefore be discarded without effect.

---

Git's revision-walking commands (`git log` and `git rev-list`) can use [`git patch-id`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-patch-id) to mark *patch-equivalent* commits.  This is not foolproof, but if a commit was cherry-picked without manual intervention, the patch IDs of the copy and the original will match.

To see how to use this, look at [the `git log` or `git rev-list` documentation](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-log) (the section about this is shared across both sets of documentation—as is the underlying implementation—so I linked to just one).  Jump down to [the section on the `--left-right` option](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-log#Documentation/git-log.txt---left-right).  Note that `--left-right` *only makes sense when combined with symmetric difference*, which in this case means using the syntax `release1...release2` or `release2...release1`.  Note that there are *three*, not two, dots, between the two names here.

Using the three dots and `--left-right`, Git will enumerate commits 5 and 4 that are reachable from `release1`, and also the two different commits 5 and 4 that are reachable from `release2`.  (Of course, Git will first enumerate commits 9, 8, 7, and 6 that are reachable from `release2`, before enumerating the 5 and 4 that are reachable from `release2` but not `release1`.  As you can see, it's probably a mistake to call these four different commits by the same two names.  They have different hash IDs for a reason: they are different commits.  Call them `5A` and `5B` and `4A` and `4B` if you like, or maybe `5.1` and `5.2` to add the release number, but give them distinct names!)

So far, that's not very much help: you have got Git showing you commits 5.1 and 4.1 from `release1`, marked with `<` or `>` depending on which side of the three dots the name `release1` is on.  And, you have Git showing you commits 9, 8, 7, 6, 5.2, and 4.2 from `release2`, marked with the other marker.  But this is the all-important starting point.  You can now switch from `--left-right` to [`--left-only`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-log#Documentation/git-log.txt---left-only) or `--right-only`, to tell Git *don't **show** me one of the two sets, even though you're still enumerating all the commits it.*

With or without the left or right only options, you can add [`--cherry-mark`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-log#Documentation/git-log.txt---cherry-mark), to tell Git: *Run `git patch-id` on every commit in both sets.  When a commit in the left-side set has the same patch ID as a commit in the right-side set, mark that commit with an equals sign `=`.  Otherwise, mark the commit with a plus-sign `+`.*

So, in this case if you run:

```
git rev-list --left-right --cherry-mark --abbrev-commit release2...release1
```

you'll see (assuming the hash ID of commit 9 starts with `999999`, etc):

```
<9999999
<8888888
<7777777
<6666666
=5200000
=4200000
=5100000
=4100000
```

So the commits you want are exactly those marked with `<`.  Using `release1...release2`, the commits you want are exactly those marked with `>`.

Assuming all of the above makes sense, now read the [`--cherry-pick` section](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-log#Documentation/git-log.txt---cherry-pick).

Note that if you had to resolve a conflict when cherry-picking, the patch IDs of the original commit and its copy *won't* match.  Such a commit *won't* be omitted by this process.  It's also possible to get a false match.  This tends to occur with a fix that just consists of, e.g., moving some opening and closing braces around: the patch ID is formed by stripping not only the line numbers, but also whitespace.  So reducing two different (by indentation and line number) brace-changing commits to patch IDs collapses commits that *should* be different.  Hence my statement at the top about this not being foolproof: you can get both false negatives (cherry-pick with merge conflict resolved) *and* false positives (conflated commits that are actually different).

Comment: The git documentation on "git log --cherry-mark" always melts my brain.

Comment: @G.SylvieDavies Here, have some some refresher for your [sanity](https://git-man-page-generator.lokaltog.net/).

Comment: I came back to this answer after a while and still impress how thoroughly it was explained. I find that I always learn something new every time with git.

Answer (score 1):

With the `git cherry` command you can find commits that have not been applied in an upstream branch. From `man git-cherry`, the synopsis looks like:

```sh
git cherry [<upstream> [<head> [<limit>]]]
```

and the description

> Determine whether there are commits in `<head>..<upstream>` that are equivalent to those in the range `<limit>..<head>`.
>
> The equivalence test is based on the diff, after removing whitespace and line numbers. `git-cherry` therefore detects when commits have been "copied" by means of `git-cherry-pick(1)`, `git-am(1)` or `git-rebase(1)`.
>
> Outputs the SHA1 of every commit in `<limit>..<head>`, prefixed with `-` for commits that have an equivalent in `<upstream>`, and `+` for commits that do not.

So, to find commits in `release2` that have no equivalent commit in `release1`, you could do

```sh
git cherry release1 release2 | grep '^+' | cut -d' ' -f2
```