# Hiding cherry picked commits in git log between 2 branches

Tags: git, git-log, cherry-pick, git-cherry-pick

Let's start with master branch

```
m1 -> m2 -> m3
```

We create a branch now. Add b1 and b2, so my branch looks like this

```
m1 -> m2 -> m3 -> b1 -> b2
```

Now master gets 2 more added

```
m1 -> m2 -> m3 -> m4 -> m5
```

I cherry pick those 2 in my branch

```
m1 -> m2 -> m3 -> b1 -> b2 -> m'4 -> m'5
```

Master has m6 and m7 added.

```
m1 -> m2 -> m3 -> m4 -> m5 -> m6 -> m7
```

Now, I want to see everything in master that's not in branch. Easy syntax

```
git log --oneline master ^branch
```

I want the above to **only show m6 and m7**

Why, because *m4* already shows up in my branch (except it shows up as *m'4* because of the cherry pick) and *m5* already shows up in my branch (except it shows up as *m'5* because of the cherry pick)

I understand cherry-picks have different hashes, but is there a way for git log to somehow identify that *m4* == *m'4* and *m5* == *m'5* and  therefore when I ask "what's in master that's not in my branch" , it hides those 2?

None of the --cherry-mark, --cherry, --cherry-pick seem to do what I want.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Git log list commits excluding cherry-picked from the first branch](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56297349/git-log-list-commits-excluding-cherry-picked-from-the-first-branch)

Comment: whoa , there seems to be a wealth of information in that page. While there seems to be no direct way to get what I need, maybe I can script something with the info from that page. Thank you!

Comment: I *think* you want `git log branch...master --cherry`; but yes, there's a lot.

Comment: You're right that there's no *direct* way to get what you want, but it's pretty easy to script once you understand the cherry marking system. You'll probably want to use `git rev-list`, fix up the hash ID list, and then run `git log --stdin --no-walk` with the commit hash IDs fed from stdin.